# No such element exception for a hyperlink

Tags: selenium

I'm using selenium webdriver 2.41.0 on win 7 with Internet Explorer 11 and having trouble clicking the "My Requests" link. HTML looks like this

```
<html class="ltr" dir="ltr">
<head>
        <body class="navigator ">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <div id="div.c16bf8b2089e8100af3b7af3edb7aefd" class="app_menu_div" style="display: block;" sclabel="false" extinct="true" appid="c16bf8b2089e8100af3b7af3edb7aefd">
                <span id="c16bf8b2089e8100af3b7af3edb7aefd" class="submenu" style="display:block;">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr id="module.dd9d893a089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae21" name="nav.module" moduleparent="c16bf8b2089e8100af3b7af3edb7aefd" moduletype="DIRECT" modulename="Dashboard" moduleid="dd9d893a089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae21">
                            <tr id="module.70fbfcf2089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae43" name="nav.module" moduleparent="c16bf8b2089e8100af3b7af3edb7aefd" moduletype="LIST" modulename="Workspace" moduleid="70fbfcf2089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae43">
                            <tr id="module.6b7b70f2089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae2c" name="nav.module" moduleparent="c16bf8b2089e8100af3b7af3edb7aefd" moduletype="DIRECT" modulename="Request" moduleid="6b7b70f2089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae2c">
                            <tr id="module.8eb40db6089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae75" name="nav.module" moduleparent="c16bf8b2089e8100af3b7af3edb7aefd" moduletype="LIST" modulename="My Requests" moduleid="8eb40db6089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae75">
                                <td class="noWrap" colspan="2">
                                    <img align="left" width="16" height="16" src="MyRequests_16.pngx"/>
                                        <h3 class="nav_menu_header">
                                            <a id="8eb40db6089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae75" class="menu" href="https://clouddev.service-now.com/sc_request_list.do?sysparm_userpref_module=8eb40db6089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae75&sysparm_query=active=true^opened_by=javascript:gs.getUserID()^EQ" data-cancelable="true" target="gsft_main" style="">My Requests</a>
                                        </h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </span>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Code I have tried so far is this

```
WebElement myReq = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("My Requests"));
myReq.click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), My Requests)]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/span/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/h3/a")).click();
```

For all of the above options, I get the

> NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath

Any other options I can try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be inside any IFrame thats why you are not getting the xpath. first switch to the IFrame and then click the web element using this xpath.

Comment: Thanks Bhupesh, i don't think there is an iFrame (can't seem to find it in HTML) but tried switching as per your suggestion by using  
    `driver.switchTo().frame("gsft_nav");`  
and got the following  

    `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame found (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

Comment: I also found that the following code works fine from the main/landing page  
    `driver.switchTo().frame("gsft_nav");`  

    `WebElement myReq = driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Requests"));`  

    `myReq.click();`  

But when I try to execute the same code from another page (request is submitted and a response is received) it throws the  No frame found exception.  
Page where no frame found exception is being thrown looks like this in Firebug <https://www.flickr.com/photos/129129215@N05/15510231959/>  
Any ideas?

Comment: when you done with your landing page , use this line in code

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

it will move focus out of current frame to webdriver. Then when you move to other page again switch to the frame on that page . i hope it will solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement myReq = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()= 'MyRequests']"));
myReq.click();
```

Comment: Thanks stamhaney. I tried your suggestion and it returned  
    `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //a[text()= 'MyRequests'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

Answer (score 0):

use  //a[contains(@id,'8eb40db6089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae75')]

or

//a[contains(text(),'My Requests')]

Any of these will work.

Keep coding

Comment: Thanks Anil, I'm afraid your suggestion returned the same result as others. Got this  
    `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == a[contains(@id,'8eb40db6089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae75')] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

Answer (score 0):

From the html code, I suspect, it's a link under a menu bar.
In that case, you have to hover over the menu bar, so that the menu items get displayed. Then, you can use the below code to click on the required item under the menu:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.movetoElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='div.c16bf8b2089e8100af3b7af3edb7aefd']"))).build().perform();
WebElement myReq = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='module.8eb40db6089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae75']//a"));
myReq.click();
```

In case, it isn't an item under a menu-bar, and is directly displayed upfront on the webpage, you can use the below code only:

```
WebElement myReq = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='module.8eb40db6089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae75']//a"));
myReq.click();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. The link is not under a menu item and is always displayed so i tried your code and it returned the following exception  
    `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //tr[@id='module.8eb40db6089e8100af3b7af3edb7ae75']//a (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

Comment: Okay. 
I happened to see your reply for @Bhupesh's answer wherein you have  added an image for the webelement.
He is right. It's a frame element. So, you have to switch to the frame and then perform the necessary actions on the element. After that you have to switch back to the default content using this code: 
`driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`
This will take you back to the default page to proceed further. Cheers.!